# Static Instances and Enums for referencing common properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, reference, static

I'm working on a problem at the moment and I've run into an issue where I have multiple architectural options, but am not sure which is going to be the best option going forward.

Context:
I am writing some code for a game, which uses a tile map. Tiles have common attributes, for example, all floor tiles are walkable, while walls are not (along with other properties). Therefore, it makes sense to have some kind of reference to which each tile can point at a common reference to discern what its properties are.

I have come up with a few solutions, however am uncertain as to which is the most efficient or will provide the greatest flexibility moving forward. Therefore, I am curious as to which would be considered 'best', either in general or for my specific case. Similarly, if there is a better way of doing this that I haven't listed, please let me know.

(As an aside, as the number of tile types grow, I may also run into the issue where it may not be practical to hard code these values and some kind of serialization or file I/O might make more sense. As I have done neither in C#, if you see any potential stumbling blocks here, it would be similarly appreciated if you could include them in your answer.)

Below are each of my three approaches, which I have simplified slightly to make them more general:

Approach #1: Enum with Extension Methods:

```
public enum TileData{
    WALL,
    FLOOR,
    FARMLAND
    //...etc
}

public static class TileDataExtensions{

    public static int IsWalkable(this TileData tile){
        switch(tile){
        case TileData.FLOOR:
        case TileData.FARMLAND:
            return true;
        case TileData.WALL:
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int IsBuildable(this TileData tile){
        switch(tile){
        case TileData.FLOOR:
            return true;
        case TileData.WALL:
        case TileData.FARMLAND:
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Zone ZoneType(this TileData tile){
        switch(tile){
        case TileData.WALL:
        case TileData.FLOOR:
            return Zone.None;
        case TileData.FARMLAND:
            return Zone.Arable;
        }
    }

    public static int TileGraphicIndex(this TileData tile){
        switch(tile){
        case TileData.WALL:
            return 0;
        case TileData.FLOOR:
            return 1;
        case TileData.FARMLAND:
            return 2;

        }
    }

    public enum Zone{
        Shipping,
        Receiving,
        Arable,
        None
    }
}
```

Approach #2: Huge Private Constructor & Static Instances

```
public class TileData{

    public bool IsWalkable{get;};
    public bool IsBuildSpace{get;};
    public Zone ZoneType{get;};
    public int TileGraphicIndex{get;};

    public static TileData FLOOR    = new TileData(true, true, Zone.None, 1);
    public static TileData WALL     = new TileData(false, false, Zone.None, 0);
    public static TileData FARMLAND = new TileData(true, false, Zone.Arable, 2);
    //...etc

    private TileData(bool walkable, bool buildSpace, Zone zone, int grahpicIndex){
        IsWalkable = walkable;
        IsBuildSpace = buildSpace;
        ZoneType = zone;
        TileGraphicIndex = grahpicIndex;
    }

    public enum Zone{
        Shipping,
        Receiving,
        Arable,
        None
    }
}
```

Approach #3: Private Constructor and Setters, with Static Instances:

```
public class TileData{

    public bool IsWalkable{get; private set;};
    public bool IsBuildSpace{get; private set;};
    public Zone ZoneType{get; private set;};
    public int TileGraphicIndex{get; private set;};


    public static TileData FLOOR{
        get{
            TileData t = new TileData();
            t.IsBuildSpace = true;
            t.TileGraphicIndex = 1;
            return t;
        }
    }
    public static TileData WALL{
        get{
            TileData t = new TileData();
            t.IsWalkable = false;
            return t;
        }
    }
    public static TileData FARMLAND{
        get{
            TileData t = new TileData();
            t.ZoneType = Zone.Arable;
            t.TileGraphicIndex = 2;
            return t;
        }
    }
    //...etc

    //Constructor applies the most common values
    private TileData(){
        IsWalkable = true;
        IsBuildSpace = false;
        ZoneType = Zone.None;
        TileGraphicIndex = 0;
    }

    public enum Zone{
        Shipping,
        Receiving,
        Arable,
        None
    }
}
```

Many thanks, LR92

**EDIT:** The types of tiles are determined before compile time by the designer, ie no class should be allowed to create new TileData types (ie, in examples 2&3, instances).

Comment: How many tile types do you anticipate having (order of magnitude)?

Comment: **Additional sub-question regarding approach 3:** Would approach 3 recreate t each time it is called (and therefore be less efficient then say, approach 2) or would this be resolved singly at compile-time/first call?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Less than 100, around 50 at most

Comment: It's recreated each time.  Make a `private static TileData _farmLand` and in the getter say `return _farmLand ?? _farmLand = new TileData() { property stuff };` . That will return _farmLand if it's not null, otherwise it will call the TileData constructor, initialize the properties, assign that to _farmLand, and return it.

Comment: ^The above is just to make approach 3 more efficient, but 2 is better anyway because it uses field accesses (very fast) instead of property accessors (slightly slower).

Comment: Thanks, I've only recently discovered these accessor tools (I'm an immigrant from Java) so I'm still learning how they work. Will fix that if I decide to go with either approach 3. My main dislike about approach 2 is if many more properties get added, the constructor is going to start to look unsightly.

Comment: @LeftRight92 Check my answer. The approach I'm suggesting involves neat and clean design. No constructors overloads required and it's easily extensible. Adding any thing new to Tile attributes won't event break anything while in case of constructor overloads adding new parameter will break all of instance where `new TileData()` would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 2 is friendly to the designer and is slightly more efficient than Approach 3.  It can also be supplemented by Approach 1's extension methods if you want to do some reasoning system-by-system instead of tile-by-tile.

Consider supplementing your constructor with a static factory:

```
private TileData(bool walkable, bool buildSpace, Zone zone, int grahpicIndex){
    IsWalkable = walkable;
    IsBuildSpace = buildSpace;
    ZoneType = zone;
    TileGraphicIndex = grahpicIndex;
}

private static TileData Tweak(TileData parent, Action<TileData> tweaks) {
    var newTile = parent.MemberwiseClone();
    tweaks(newTile);
    return newTile;
}
```

This allows you to build your tile types with a sort of prototypal inheritance (except instead of looking up the chain of prototypes at runtime, it will be baked in).  This should be very useful as it is common in tile-based games to have tiles that are mostly similar but have slightly different behaviors or graphics.

```
public readonly static TileData GRASS =          new TileData(etc.);
public readonly static TileData WAVY_GRASS =     Tweak(GRASS, g => g.TileGraphicIndex = 10);
public readonly static TileData JERKFACE_GRASS = Tweak(GRASS, g => g.IsWalkable = false);
public readonly static TileData SWAMP_GRASS =    Tweak(GRASS, g => {g.TileGraphicIndex = 11; g.IsBuildable = false;});
```

Note: when you serialize/deserialize your tile maps, you'll want to have a consistent ID of some sort assigned to each tile (in particular, this makes working with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) easier).  You could pass that in to the constructor (and to Tweak, as another argument, because otherwise the tweaked tile will have cloned the ID of its parent!).  It would be good then to have something (a unit test would be fine) that ensures that all fields of this class of type TileData have distinct IDs.  Finally, to avoid having to re-enter these IDs into Tiled, you could make something that exports the data from this class into a [Tiled TSX or TMX file](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/#tileset) (or similar file for whatever map editor you ultimately go with).

**EDIT:** One last tip.  If your consistent IDs are consecutive ints, you can "compile" your tile data into static arrays split out by property.  This can be useful for systems in which performance is important (for example, pathfinding will need to look up walkability a lot).

```
public static TileData[] ById = typeof(TileData)
                                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(TileData))
                                .Select(f => f.GetValue(null))
                                .Cast<TileData>()
                                .OrderBy(td => td.Id)
                                .ToArray();
public static bool[] Walkable = ById.Select(td => td.IsWalkable).ToArray();

// now you can have your map just be an array of array of ids
// and say things like: if(TileData.Walkable[map[y][x]]) {etc.}
```

If your ids are not consecutive ints, you can use `Dictionary<MyIdType, MyPropertyType>` for the same purpose and access it with the same syntax, but it wouldn't perform as well.

Comment: I'm going to have to look up the definition of Action<> but this looks promising...think I understand it though.

Comment: Additionally, I haven't used extension methods outside the context of enums. Would the approach be vertically identical?

Comment: Extension methods can go on any type.  The syntax for the extension method signature would be unchanged from your example.

Comment: Will try this method out in the morning, looks like it's most fits what I'm after.

Comment: how would you modify this to allow for multiple actions. For example, if I wanted to change one of the bools and the tile graphic index?

Comment: Edited, with some extra notes.

Comment: Many thanks, haven't worked with serialization, so will have to tackle that at some point, so there may be another question in the future on that front. Thank you again, accepted answer.

Comment: Added note about making accessing TileData convenient and performant.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to solve your requirement with more object oriented approach. `Less conditional more polymorphism`. In my opinion if you have more chances to come up with new Types of Tiles apart from the mentioned ones. Means the design should be extensible and should be open for minimal change to introduce new component.

For e.g. Let's keep the Tile class a base class.

```
public abstract class Tile
{
    public Tile()
    {
        // Default attributes of a Tile
        IsWalkable = false;
        IsBuildSpace = false;
        ZoneType = Zone.None;
        GraphicIndex = -1;
    }

    public virtual bool IsWalkable { get; private set; }
    public virtual bool IsBuildSpace { get; private set; }
    public virtual Zone ZoneType { get; private set; }
    public virtual int GraphicIndex { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Factory to build the derived types objects
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Get<T>() where T : Tile, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Now we have defined a Tile with default attributes. If required more default attributes of a Tile can be added as Vitual properties. Since this class is `abstract` one can not simply create the object so a Derived class has to be introduced which would be our specific type of Tile e.g. Wall, Floor etc.

```
public class Floor : Tile
{
    public override bool IsBuildSpace
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool IsWalkable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    public override int GraphicIndex
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

public class Wall : Tile
{
    public override int GraphicIndex
    {
        get {  return 0; }
    }

    public override Zone ZoneType
    {
        get { return Zone.Arable; }
    }
}
```

If a new type of tile has to be created. Just inherit the class from Tile and Override the properties which would require to have specific values instead of defaults.

Crafting a tile would be done via base class just by invoking the generic static factory method Get<>() that will only accept a derived type of Tile:

```
        Tile wallLeft = Tile.Get<Wall>();
        Tile floor = Tile.Get<Floor>();
```

So Everything is Tile and represents a different set of values of defined properties. They can be identified Either by their type or values of properties. And more importantly as you can see we got rid of all the `If..Else`, `Switch case`, `Constructor overloads`. Hows that sound?

**Extending the Tile with new attributes**

So for e.g. a new property/attribute is required on Tiles e.g. Color simple add a Virtual property to Tile class named Color. In constructor give it a default value. Optinally (not mandatory) Override the property in child classes if your tile should be in special color.

**Introducing new Type of Tile**

Simply derive the New Tile type with `Tile` class and override required properties.

Comment: As clever and about as pure OO as this is, I can't help but feel that creating a new (albeit derived) class for every type of tile is a lot of overhead. A good response though, so +1

Comment: Glad you liked it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just overload the constructor?

```
public class TileData{

    public bool IsWalkable{get;};
    public bool IsBuildSpace{get;};
    public Zone ZoneType{get;};
    public int TileGraphicIndex{get;};

    public static TileData FLOOR    = new TileData(true, true, Zone.None, 1);
    public static TileData WALL     = new TileData(false, false, Zone.None, 0);
    public static TileData FARMLAND = new TileData(true, false, Zone.Arable, 2);
    //...etc

    public TileData(bool walkable, bool buildSpace, Zone zone, int grahpicIndex){
        IsWalkable = walkable;
        IsBuildSpace = buildSpace;
        ZoneType = zone;
        TileGraphicIndex = grahpicIndex;
    }

    public TileData(){
        IsWalkable = true;
        IsBuildSpace = false;
        ZoneType = Zone.None;
        TileGraphicIndex = 0;
    }

    public enum Zone{
        Shipping,
        Receiving,
        Arable,
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: because I don't want the constructor to be publicly accessible. The types of tiles available are pre-determined (at compile time). Apologies, should have made that more obvious in my original post.

Comment: Nothing wrong with overloaded private constructors.

Comment: Because it's *two* out of your *three* solutions all in *one*

Comment: I guess, but I feel like mixing and matching between the two ways of creating the static instances will just end up slightly confusing...I don't see the benefit of it that way.

Answer (score 0):

What about methods to create each type of tile.

```
public class Tile{
    public TileType Type { get; private set; }
    public bool IsWalkable { get; private set; }
    public bool IsBuildSpace { get; private set; }
    public Zone ZoneType { get; private set; }
    public int TileGraphicIndex { get; private set; }

    private Tile() {
    }

    public static Tile BuildTile(TileType type){
        switch (type) {
            case TileType.WALL:
                return BuildWallTile();
            case TileType.FLOOR:
                return BuildFloorTile();
            case TileType.FARMLAND:
                return BuildFarmlandTile();
            default:
                throw ArgumentException("type");
        }
    }

    public static Tile BuildWallTile()
    {
        return new Tile {
            IsWalkable = false,
            IsBuildSpace = false,
            ZoneType = Zone.None,
            TileGraphicIndex = 1,
            Type = TileType.WALL
        };
    }

    public static Tile BuildFloorTile()
    {
        return new Tile {
            IsWalkable = true,
            IsBuildSpace = None,
            ZoneType = Zone.None,
            TileGraphicIndex = 1,
            Type = TileType.FLOOR
        };
    }

    public static Tile BuildFarmlandTile()
    {
        return new Tile {
            IsWalkable = true,
            IsBuildSpace = false,
            ZoneType = Zone.Arable,
            TileGraphicIndex = 2,
            Type = TileType.FARMLAND
        };
    }

    public enum Zone{
        Shipping,
        Receiving,
        Arable,
        None
    }
    public enum TileType{
        WALL,
        FLOOR,
        FARMLAND
        //...etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking this is a factory pattern?

Comment: It is very similar, yes

Comment: Also, other than switching the approach from static instances to methods, in what way does this differ from approach 3 (in the original question) in practical terms?

Comment: It actually doesn't, I misunderstood that approach

Answer (score 0):

Just extending on Diegos answer, the methods can just be fields for cleanliness

```
public class Tile{
    public TileType Type { get; private set; }
    public bool IsWalkable { get; private set; }
    public bool IsBuildSpace { get; private set; }
    public Zone ZoneType { get; private set; }
    public int TileGraphicIndex { get; private set; }
    private Tile() { }

    public static Tile BuildTile(TileType type){
        switch (type) {
        case TileType.WALL: return BuildWallTile();
        case TileType.FLOOR: return BuildFloorTile();
        case TileType.FARMLAND: return BuildFarmlandTile();
        default: throw ArgumentException("type");
        }
    }
    public static Tile wall {
        get {
            return new Tile {
                IsWalkable = false, 
                IsBuildSpace = false, 
                ZoneType = Zone.None, 
                TileGraphicIndex = 1,
                Type = TileType.WALL
             };
         }
     }
     public static Tile floor {
          get {
              return new Tile {
                  IsWalkable = true, 
                  IsBuildSpace = None, 
                  ZoneType = Zone.None, 
                  TileGraphicIndex = 1,
                  Type = TileType.FLOOR
              };
          }
     }
     public static Tile farmland {
         get {
             return new Tile {
                 IsWalkable = true, 
                 IsBuildSpace = false, 
                 ZoneType = Zone.Arable, 
                 TileGraphicIndex = 2, 
                 Type = TileType.FARMLAND
              };
          }
    }
    public enum Zone{
        Shipping,
        Receiving,
        Arable,
        None
    }
    public enum TileType{ WALL, FLOOR, FARMLAND //...etc }
}
```

Usage:

```
Tile myWallTile = Tile.wall;
Tile myFloorTile = Tile.floor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to present a totally different (and self admittedly insane) approach from the many suggestions thus far.  If you're willing to totally throw type safety out the window, consider this:

```
public interface IValueHolder
{
    object Value {get; set;}
}

public class IsWalkable : Attribute, IValueHolder
{
    public object Value {get; set;}
    public IsWalkable(bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class IsBuildSpace : Attribute, IValueHolder
{
    public object Value {get; set;}
    public IsBuildSpace(bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public enum Zone
{
    None,
    Arable,
}

public class ZoneType : Attribute, IValueHolder
{
    public object Value {get; set;}
    public ZoneType(Zone value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class TileGraphicIndex : Attribute, IValueHolder
{
    public object Value {get; set;}
    public TileGraphicIndex(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class TileAttributeCollector
{
    protected readonly Dictionary<string, object> _attrs;

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_attrs.ContainsKey(key)) return _attrs[key];
            else return null;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_attrs.ContainsKey(key)) _attrs[key] = value;
            else _attrs.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public TileAttributeCollector()
    {
        _attrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        Attribute[] attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(this.GetType()); 
        foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            IValueHolder vAttr = attr as IValueHolder;
            if (vAttr != null)
            {
                this[vAttr.ToString()]= vAttr.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}

[IsWalkable(true), IsBuildSpace(false), ZoneType(Zone.Arable), TileGraphicIndex(2)]
public class FarmTile : TileAttributeCollector
{
}
```

An example of usage:

```
FarmTile tile = new FarmTile();

// read, can be null.
var isWalkable = tile["IsWalkable"];

// write
tile["IsWalkable"] = false;

// add at runtime.
tile["Mom"]= "Ingrid Carlson of Norway";
```